# Get image from SharePoint by URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, ajax, sharepoint-hosted-app

I try to get an Image from SharePoint by using JavaScript code. I have the complete URL of the image which is stored in a SharePoint Assets Library. My app is SharePoint hosted. This code does not work:

```
var fileUrl;

var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

clientContext.load(oWebsite);
var base = this;

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var fileUrl = "/sites/collection/assets/picture.jpg";

    var digest = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: fileUrl,
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 500,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": digest
        },
        success: (response) => {
            base.successHandler(response);
        },
        error: (xhr) => {
            base.errorHandler();
        }
    });
```

I get no error.

Comment: Are you trying to read image bytes?

Comment: Yes, I need the bytes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10646659/1375553

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use `XMLHttpRequest` for this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        //this.response is what you're looking for
        handler(this.response);
        console.log(this.response, typeof this.response);
        var img = document.getElementById('img');
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        img.src = url.createObjectURL(this.response);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', fileUrl);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob